# Props displays in template but not in functions

Tags: vuejs2

My **_id prop is nicely displaying in this child template**, but console.log(this._id) showing nothing in function , not even 'undefined' this is my child template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    LIST
    {{ _id }} // OK , I CAN SEE IT 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
export default {
  name: "messages",
  props: ["_id"],
  data() {
    return {
      messages: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getMessages: function() {
      console.log(this._id);  // NOTHING SHOWN
      axios
        .post(this.server + "getMessages", { _id: this._id })
        .then(response => {
          this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this._id); // NOTHING SHOWN
    this.getMessages();
  }
};
</script>
```

Please help me,i can't understand this behavior . How can it be possible please, not any of the console.log (this._id) is working, how can I get the _id prop variable then ?

Edit : this is my component call in my parent template :

```
 <messages :_id="this.user._id"></messages>
```

**EDIT 2 :**
Oh I think I know, it's because **this.user._id** comes asynchronously from the parent axios call  , so it s not there in time ! 
**This is working , I can console.log(this._id) in the child with this:**

```
<messages :_id="1111111111"></messages>
```

Is there any way to wait for **this.user._id** to get populated before calling the child component ?

***RESOLVED BY phen0menon***

Comment: Are you informing `_id`'s value when you add your component to the template?

Comment: yes cause it is shown in the child template . I will add it to the post thank you

Comment: Have you tried bracket syntax (`this['_id']`)?

Comment: Thank you, no still a blank with console.log(this['_id'])...

Comment: Oh I think I know, it's because this.user._id comes asynchronous , so it s not there in time !

Comment: @harmoniuscool try accessing props via `this.$props._id`

Comment: Thank you, tried out it with no luck console.log(this.$props._id); What is strange is that I see the _id variable nicely displayed  inside of my template ! I guess the child methods must be called before ....

Comment: @harmoniuscool you can use conditional rendering if you need so. `<some-component v-if="someCondition"></some-component>`

Comment: Very cool ! Lets try !

Comment: Yeees ! You're very nice thank youuu ! it works now !

Comment: @harmoniuscool to make it clear, you can accept my answer if I helped you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you access a property that could be dynamically presented in the parent component.

To solve that, use [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) to any child component that should get any dynamic props in this way:

```
<template>
  <child-component v-if="someData"></child-component>
</template>
```